# HTTP.GET Request Inside Past Event Issue

Tags: angular, angular7

When I try to use a past event to get some data from my API, it turn out that I loose the data outside subscribe block, I tried doing this with a service not inside the component but I still have the same behaviour.

```
    myObject :SomeType;

    onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
    let clipboardData = event.clipboardData ;
    let pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text');
    try {
      this.http.get(this.rootUrl+'/sometoken/'+pastedText.trim()).subscribe(
        res => {
          this.myObject = res as SomeType;
          console.log('Value1: '+this.myObject.value1);// value here is exist
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
      console.log('Value1: '+this.myObject.value1);// value here is undefined!
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Basic asynchronous issue, your request hasn't completed before you do the console log. Is it your first time with RxJS ?

Comment: @trichetriche Thank you, how to make sure it is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use RxJS, you use asynchronous programming. It is like using Promises.

To make it simple, here is a snippet that creates an observable, then emits after a second.

```js
const obs = rxjs.of('Async').pipe(
  rxjs.operators.delay(1000)
);

let val = '(empty)';

obs.subscribe(value =>{
   val = value;
   console.log('Inside of subscribe, val = ', val);
});

console.log('Outside of subscribe, val = ', val);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

as you can see, it only works **in the subscribe callback**. Again, to make it simple and resolve your issue, consider that only callbacks are up-to-date when you need your data.

I urge you to read [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/observables) if you wish to work with Angular (and RxJS implicitly) because without understanding it, you will have a very hard time using the framework !

Comment: I already read some of the docs but I thought since it is updating a local object the data should be kept locally! Any way, Thanks